# My Java applets won't run in HTML

Tags: google-chrome, security, browser, java, html

My Java applet runs fine when I open the HTML in AppletViewer, but when I open the html in like Chrome, it just says "Error, click for more details" and the details say that my security options prevent it from running.
I tried setting my security level to medium in the Java Control Panel but it changed nothing.
How do I fix this?

Comment: If you enter `about:plugins` in the Chrome address bar, is Java enabled? If it's not and you see an Enable link next to Java, click it and try running your applets.

Answer (score 0):

make sure that you have the latest version of java. Java has been very insecure these days, so modern browsers block it by default, if a known security problem is unsolved. but usually you can force the browser to run it, but at your own risk. (you can find the java settings under settings, extentions (chrome) or firefox,add-ons, extensions